# Twilio PHP Helper LIbrary

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I am using the Twilio PHP Helper Library.
 When using Twilio/Twiml Class it appears that when adding an Attribute,  Ampersands ( "&") are escaped.  This appears to be an underlying code issue that uses SimpleXML libraries.  However that said,  I am trying to append variables to a URL string to be used by the CallBack.  and the '&" are needed.

```
$response = new Twilio\Twiml();
$action = "test.php?name=value&name2=value2";
$response->record( 
array( 
 'action' => $action ,  
 'maxLength' => '120' 
));
```

The & (Ampersand) is replaced with `&amp;`

Comment: Has this caused a problem when used with Twilio? While the ampersands are encoded for the XML, when they are decoded they should just be an ampersand.

Comment: I will try again and report back

Answer (score 0):

use & instated off &

```
 $response = new Twilio\Twiml();
 $action = "test.php?name=value&amp;name2=value2";
 $response->record( 
 array( 
 'action' => $action ,  
 'maxLength' => '120' 
 ));
```